# if user input is an element of a list

Tags: python, list, loops, subset, element

I think there must be a simple solution to this, but I can't find it.
If user input is equal to an element of a list, then the if statement should evaluate to `true`:

```
animalslist = ['bear', 'giraffe', 'wolf', 'lion', 'rabbit', 'monkey', 'scorpion']             
animalnumber = int(input("\nEnter a number between 0 and 6 inclusive.\n"))

print "You have summoned a %s..." % animalslist[animalnumber]

if animalslist[animalnumber] == "scorpion" or "wolf" or "lion" or "bear":
    #or perhaps using the integer - if animalslist[animalnumber] == 0 or 2 or 3 or 5:
    print "That is a vicious predator. You = dinner. The End.\n\n"

else:
    ...
```

Comment: Minor note - you're looking to match an element of the list, not a subset. A subset implies the input is a list of multiple elements, which must match a subset of your list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use another list.
Example:

```py
animalslist = ['bear', 'giraffe', 'wolf', 'lion', 'rabbit', 'monkey', 'scorpion']   
predatorlist = ["scorpion", "wolf", "lion", "bear"]
if animalslist[animalnumber] in predatorlist:
    print "That is a vicious predator. You = dinner. The End.\n\n"
```

Comment: A set is better in this case, because it is faster to lookup something in a set.

Comment: It really does not matter at all for this application.

Comment: @Vincent No, not for this specific problem, but there is a pedagogical interest in using simple cases to teach people about the impact of the choices they make.

Comment: @NathanielFord You are of course correct. However as this clearly seems to be a beginner question I value using less (possibly confusing due to their similarities) different types to achieve the same goal. :)
If my goal was to create the best solution regardless of the person asking the question it would probably be even better to use a dictionary or classes to have a single source of truth instead of 2 different lists that will have to be updated independetly.

Comment: @Vincent I agree - mostly. I think it is pretty important for beginners to learn about basic building blocks so they choose the right one naturally. Here the natural building block is a set. We don't care about order, and we don't need repeats, and it is a faster lookup. The beginner absolutely should be asking the question 'what is the right data structure?' - so many people fail to learn that, and it makes a lot of problems a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
animalslist = ['bear', 'giraffe', 'wolf', 'lion', 'rabbit', 'monkey', 'scorpion']             
animalnumber = int(input("\nEnter a number between 0 and 6 inclusive.\n"))
predators = {"scorpion", "wolf", "lion", "bear"}

print "You have summoned a %s..." % animalslist[animalnumber]

if animalslist[animalnumber] in predators:
    print "That is a vicious predator. You = dinner. The End.\n\n"
else:
    ...
```

Answer (score -2):

An alternative is to restructure your data, knowing the usage you have for it. This is not dissimilar to @JhanzaibHumayun's answer in terms of semantics, but is another way to think about it:

```
animals = {
  'bear': True,
  'giraffe': False,
  'wolf': True,
  'lion': True,
  'rabbit': False,
  'monkey': False, 
  'scorpion': True,
}

choice = int(input(f"\nEnter a number between 0 and {len(animals)} inclusive.\n"))
summoned = [*animals][choice]
print f"You have summoned a {summoned}..."
if animals.get(summoned):
    print f"Summoned is a vicious predator. You = dinner. The End. \n\n"
```

This relates the data about animals and whether they're a predator or not (true/false) in a single data structure. This is no more or less computationally expensive than storing it in two lists, and probably saves a few licks of memory. You could take it a step further by storing additional information beyond their predator nature, though at that point you might want to think about a dataclass.